# MySql JavaEE загрузка .img на .jsp

Tags: mysql, java-ee

Всем привет. Хочу поместить изображение .img в базу данных и потом оттуда их использовать в проекте на сайте. картинки не большие , 800*600 .jpg . Как лучше реализовать ?

Comment: Картинки в базе данных, это вообще легально?

Comment: да решил попробовать через mysql BLOP img . А что посоветуете ? не морочить себе голову ? я думал сначала перевести картинки в RGB код классом java и поместить их бд . Пока они у меня все на classpath в img хранятся

Comment: Ну как вариант конечно можно, просто непривычно как то, а почему просто не положить все картинки в папку с ресурсами? или они у вас как то динамически появляются?

Comment: по задумке - динамически. у меня две страницы .jsp которые все выполняют, вместо 40-ка страниц html. некоторые картинки рэндомно будут вставляться. вся информация будет динамическая на сайте. Не разу так не пробывал , но вот прочел , что в MySQL оператор BLOB может хранить img.

Comment: т.е. вы в  момент сборки проекта не имеете возможности положить все картинки в папку с ресурсами!?

Comment: имею. я же выше писал, что они сейчас находятся в classpath в img. это и есть папка с ресурсами. все отлично работает. но идея сделать волшебство )

Comment: Я вас понял, ну пробоуйте!

Comment: ну спасибо ))))